# Unable to figure out a mysterious link failure in Freeswitch

Tags: visual-c++, freeswitch

While trying to link a Freeswitch endpoint (mod_h323) in VS2012, I get the following error.

------ Build started: Project: mod_h323, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'c:/opensource/freeswitch-1.2.22/libs/openssl-1.0.1c/lib/VC/libeay32MDd.lib'

I am simply unable to find out where this link instruction is specified. I would like to point to a different library file, but where is this link instruction hidden? I am unable to get past this error.

Edit: What are the different ways of specifying link libraries in VC++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should check if the library is specified at the linker command line. In the project Property Page navigate to

```
- Configuration Properties
  - Linker
     -Command Line
```

If you find the lib here, you have passed it in the project properties. If not the library request can be added by a `#pragma comment` directives. To find the object (or library) file with that directive you have to dump all directives with the command

```
for %o in (*.obj *.lib) do dumpbin /directives %o
```

When you fond the object file, you need to find the corresponding pragma in the source file.

Comment: Thanks, I found the hardcoded pragma comment in the ptlib library source code. Since ptlib is an external library, I wasn't looking at it.